# How do you write BigInt to file in Julia?

Tags: julia

I'm trying to write very big numbers to a file but I get the error that write() doesn't accept BigInt as an argument.

```
open("twosPow.txt","w") do f
    for i in 1:10
        write(f,BigInt(2)^10^i);
    end
end
```

ERROR: MethodError: no method matching write(::IOStream, ::BigInt)

I also can't find a way to convert BigInt to string.

Comment: Note that you also need to separate the values in some fashion, for example with a space or comma, so that a subsequent read() can split the digits between numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`write(f,string(BigInt(2)^10^i))` will do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to convert to a string if you `print` the number to the file directly instead of `write`-ing it.

```
open("twosPow.txt","w") do f
    for i in 1:9
        print(f,big(2)^10^i)
    end
end
```

Also note that the exponent 10_000_000_000 is too large for a `BigInt`, `2^10^10` will overflow.